# Is there any way to use full or outer join in mongodb other than using $lookup for left join?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want some additional fields from the other collection to be used in my current collection aggregation, without using any $lookup function , while using $lookup it is taking only matched data , but I need something like outer join that we use in sql.

Comment: It would be better if you can provide testing data and expected result in a valid JSON by editing your own question. Ask a question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71218971/perform-a-conditional-lookup-and-add-custom-data-if-from-collection-has-no-data) would be more clarify for us to solve your problem. Be sure that your testing data can come up with your expected result in certain logic.

Comment: `$lookup` works exactly like an `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. FULL or CROSS joins you can construct from [$facet](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/)